# Subsetting into several data frames by identifier in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to subset a data frame in Python by identifier. For instance, suppose we have the below data:

```
ID    Number
A     50
A     45
A     21
B     78
B     79
B     12
C     15
C     74
C     10
```

I want to split the data into three separate data frames, i.e. all data for A would be the first data frame, B would be the second, C the third.

I'm having trouble going about this. I've tried using **set** for unique values but am thinking this is not the way to go about it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `A, B, C = [df for _,df in df.groupby('ID')]` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: also , i am confused why not create list of `Dataframe`

Comment: I see you are an R user. Had this been an R question, perfect use for `by` or `subset`.

Comment: @Abdou Your solution worked, many thanks.

Comment: @Parfait Yep, you guessed it. Had written the same code using subset in R but wanted to know the equivalent in Python.

Comment: IDK whether my solution work for you?

Comment: @Wen: No, sorry, I can't understand how you are defining dfA from the code you wrote. Abdou's solution was simpler.

Comment: I notice you are an R user , try to think about function `variables` is almost the same with function `assign` in R

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? (PS: I consider auto assign name to `Dataframe`)

```
variables = locals()
for i in df['ID'].unique():
    variables["df{0}".format(i)] = df.loc[df.ID == i,]

dfA
Out[147]: 
  ID  Number
0  A       1
3  A       1
6  A       1
```